# Yocto bitbake ${@bb.utils.contains(...)} is having subtistution failure

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to integrate meta-mender and the problem comes down to the file path:

meta-mender/meta-mender-core/classes/mender-part-images.classes

On the line:

```
56:     if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','mender-uboot','true','false',d)}; then
```

It shoots out:

```
temp/run.do_image_sdimg.3123112: 125: Bad substitution
```

The syntax for bitbake is right, and this is written by mender themselves. So what else could possibly cause this issue?

EDIT = Added the file that is having a problem as a request from comment

```
# Class that creates an SD card image that boots under qemu's emulation
# for vexpress-a9 board. See the script mender-qemu for an example of
# how to boot the image.

# The partitioning scheme is:
#    part1: FAT partition with bootloader
#    part2: first rootfs, active
#    part3: second rootfs, inactive, mirror of first,
#           available as failsafe for when some update fails
#    part4: persistent data partition
#    partx: extra user defined partition

python() {
    deprecated_vars = ['SDIMG_DATA_PART_DIR', 'SDIMG_DATA_PART_SIZE_MB',
                       'SDIMG_BOOT_PART_SIZE_MB', 'SDIMG_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT_MB']
    for varname in deprecated_vars:
        cur = d.getVar(varname, True)
        if cur:
            newvarname = varname.replace('SDIMG_', 'MENDER_')
            bb.fatal('Detected use of deprecated var %s, please replace it with %s in your setup' % (varname, newvarname))
}

inherit image
inherit image_types
inherit mender-helpers

# This normally defaults to .rootfs which is misleading as this is not a simple
# rootfs image and causes problems if one wants to use something like this:
#
#    IMAGE_FSTYPES += "sdimg.gz"
#
# Above assumes that the image name is:
#
#    ${IMAGE_NAME}${IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX}.${type}
#
# Which results in a empty "gz" archive when using the default value, in our
# case IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX should be empty as we do not use it when naming
# our image.
IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX = ""


################################################################################
# Block storage
################################################################################

mender_part_image() {
    suffix="$1"
    ptable_type="$2"
    boot_part_params="$3"

    set -ex
    mkdir -p "${WORKDIR}"
    if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','mender-uboot','true','false',d)}; then
        # Copy the files to embed in the WIC image into ${WORKDIR} for exclusive access
        install -m 0644 "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/uboot.env" "${WORKDIR}/"
    fi

    ondisk_dev="$(basename "${MENDER_STORAGE_DEVICE}")"

    wks="${WORKDIR}/mender-$suffix.wks"
    rm -f "$wks"
    if [ -n "${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" ]; then
        # Copy the files to embed in the WIC image into ${WORKDIR} for exclusive access
        install -m 0644 "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" "${WORKDIR}/"

        if [ $(expr ${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_BOOTSECTOR_OFFSET} % 2) -ne 0 ]; then
            # wic doesn't support fractions of kiB, so we need to do some tricks
            # when we are at an odd sector: Create a new bootloader file that
            # lacks the first 512 bytes, write that at the next even sector,
            # which coincides with a whole kiB, and then write the missing
            # sector manually afterwards.
            bootloader_sector=$(expr ${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_BOOTSECTOR_OFFSET} + 1)
            bootloader_file=${WORKDIR}/${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}-partial
            dd if=${WORKDIR}/${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE} of=$bootloader_file skip=1
        else
            bootloader_sector=${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_BOOTSECTOR_OFFSET}
            bootloader_file=${WORKDIR}/${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}
        fi
        bootloader_align_kb=$(expr $(expr $bootloader_sector \* 512) / 1024)
        bootloader_size=$(stat -c '%s' "$bootloader_file")
        bootloader_end=$(expr $bootloader_align_kb \* 1024 + $bootloader_size)
        if [ $bootloader_end -gt ${MENDER_UBOOT_ENV_STORAGE_DEVICE_OFFSET} ]; then
            bberror "Size of bootloader specified in MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE" \
                    "exceeds MENDER_UBOOT_ENV_STORAGE_DEVICE_OFFSET, which is" \
                    "reserved for U-Boot environment storage. Please raise it" \
                    "manually."
        fi
        cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
# embed bootloader
part --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=$bootloader_file" --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --align $bootloader_align_kb --no-table
EOF
    fi

    if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'mender-uboot', 'true', 'false', d)} && [ -n "${MENDER_UBOOT_ENV_STORAGE_DEVICE_OFFSET}" ]; then
        boot_env_align_kb=$(expr ${MENDER_UBOOT_ENV_STORAGE_DEVICE_OFFSET} / 1024)
        cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
part --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=${WORKDIR}/uboot.env" --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --align $boot_env_align_kb --no-table
EOF
    fi

    if [ $(expr ${MENDER_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT} % 1024 || true) -ne 0 ]; then
        bbfatal "MENDER_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT must be KiB aligned when using partition table."
    fi

    alignment_kb=$(expr ${MENDER_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT} / 1024)

    # Used for all Linux filesystem partitions.
    if [ "$ptable_type" = "gpt" ]; then
        part_type_params="--part-type 8300"
    else
        part_type_params=
    fi

    # remove leading and trailing spaces
    IMAGE_BOOT_FILES_STRIPPED=$(echo "${IMAGE_BOOT_FILES}" | sed -r 's/(^\s*)|(\s*$)//g')

    if [ "${MENDER_BOOT_PART_SIZE_MB}" -ne "0" ]; then
        mender_merge_bootfs_and_image_boot_files
        cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
part --source rootfs --rootfs-dir ${WORKDIR}/bootfs.${BB_CURRENTTASK} --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --fstype=vfat --label boot --align $alignment_kb --fixed-size ${MENDER_BOOT_PART_SIZE_MB} --active $boot_part_params
EOF
    elif [ -n "$IMAGE_BOOT_FILES_STRIPPED" ]; then
        bbwarn "MENDER_BOOT_PART_SIZE_MB is set to zero, but IMAGE_BOOT_FILES is not empty. The files are being omitted from the image."
    fi

    cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
part --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.${ARTIFACTIMG_FSTYPE}" --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --align $alignment_kb --fixed-size ${MENDER_CALC_ROOTFS_SIZE}k $part_type_params
part --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --fstype=${ARTIFACTIMG_FSTYPE} --align $alignment_kb --fixed-size ${MENDER_CALC_ROOTFS_SIZE}k $part_type_params
EOF

    if [ "${MENDER_SWAP_PART_SIZE_MB}" -ne "0" ]; then
        cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
part swap --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --fstype=swap --label swap --align $alignment_kb --size ${MENDER_SWAP_PART_SIZE_MB}
EOF
    fi

    cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
part --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.dataimg" --ondisk "$ondisk_dev" --align $alignment_kb --fixed-size ${MENDER_DATA_PART_SIZE_MB} $part_type_params
EOF
    # added extra partitions if exists
    cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
${@get_extra_parts_wks(d)}
EOF

    cat >> "$wks" <<EOF
bootloader --ptable $ptable_type
EOF


    echo "### Contents of wks file ###"
    cat "$wks"
    echo "### End of contents of wks file ###"

    # Call WIC
    outimgname="${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}.$suffix"
    wicout="${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}-$suffix"
    BUILDDIR="${TOPDIR}" wic create "$wks" --vars "${STAGING_DIR}/${MACHINE}/imgdata/" -e "${IMAGE_BASENAME}" -o "$wicout/" ${WIC_CREATE_EXTRA_ARGS}
    mv "$wicout/$(basename "${wks%.wks}")"*.direct "$outimgname"

    if [ -n "${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" ] && [ ${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_BOOTSECTOR_OFFSET} -ne $bootloader_sector ]; then
        # We need to write the first sector of the bootloader. See comment above
        # where bootloader_sector is set.
        dd if=${WORKDIR}/${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE} of="$outimgname" seek=${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_BOOTSECTOR_OFFSET} count=1 conv=notrunc
    fi

    if [ -n "${MENDER_MBR_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" ]; then
        dd if="${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${MENDER_MBR_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" of="$outimgname" bs=${MENDER_MBR_BOOTLOADER_LENGTH} count=1 conv=notrunc
    fi

    rm -rf "$wicout/"

    # Pad the image up to the alignment. This matters mostly for the emulator,
    # which uses the file size to determine the size of the storage device,
    # which must be a multiple of its device block size. However, it might be
    # beneficial for real storage media as well, to make sure the final sector
    # is cleared out when flashing the image. May increase image size slightly,
    # but should compress well!
    alignment=${MENDER_PARTITION_ALIGNMENT}
    pad_size=$(expr \( $(stat -c %s "$outimgname") + $alignment - 1 \) / $alignment \* $alignment)
    truncate -s $pad_size "$outimgname"

    # If we padded above, and the partition table type is GPT, we need to
    # relocate the trailing backup header to the new end to avoid warnings.
    if [ "$ptable_type" = "gpt" ]; then
        sgdisk -e "$outimgname"
    fi

    if [ "$ptable_type" = "msdos" ]; then
        # Fix partition entry types for MBR style partition table.
        (
            echo t                                  # Partition type
            echo ${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_A_NUMBER}     # Number of partition
            echo 83                                 # "Linux filesystem" type

            echo t                                  # Partition type
            echo ${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_B_NUMBER}     # Number of partition
            echo 83                                 # "Linux filesystem" type

            echo t                                  # Partition type
            echo ${MENDER_DATA_PART_NUMBER}         # Number of partition
            echo 83                                 # "Linux filesystem" type

            echo w                                  # Save and exit
        ) | fdisk ${outimgname}
    fi

    if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'mender-partuuid', 'true', 'false', d)}; then
        if [ "$ptable_type" = "gpt" ]; then
            # Set Fixed PARTUUID for all devices
            sgdisk -u ${MENDER_BOOT_PART_NUMBER}:${@mender_get_partuuid_from_device(d, '${MENDER_BOOT_PART}')} "$outimgname"
            sgdisk -u ${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_A_NUMBER}:${@mender_get_partuuid_from_device(d, '${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_A}')} "$outimgname"
            sgdisk -u ${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_B_NUMBER}:${@mender_get_partuuid_from_device(d, '${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_B}')} "$outimgname"
            sgdisk -u ${MENDER_DATA_PART_NUMBER}:${@mender_get_partuuid_from_device(d, '${MENDER_DATA_PART}')} "$outimgname"
        else
            diskIdent=$(echo ${@mender_get_partuuid_from_device(d, '${MENDER_ROOTFS_PART_A}')} | cut -d- -f1)
            # For MBR Set the Disk Identifier.  Drives follow the pattern of <Disk Identifier>-<Part Number>
            (
                echo x                              # Enter expert mode
                echo i                              # Set disk identifier
                echo 0x${diskIdent}                 # Identifier
                echo r                              # Exit expert mode
                echo w                              # Write changes
            ) | fdisk ${outimgname}
        fi
    fi
}

IMAGE_CMD_sdimg() {
    mender_part_image sdimg msdos
}
IMAGE_CMD_uefiimg() {
    mender_part_image uefiimg gpt "--part-type EF00"
}
IMAGE_CMD_biosimg() {
    mender_part_image biosimg msdos
}
IMAGE_CMD_gptimg() {
    mender_part_image gptimg gpt
}


addtask do_rootfs_wicenv after do_image before do_image_sdimg
addtask do_rootfs_wicenv after do_image before do_image_uefiimg
addtask do_rootfs_wicenv after do_image before do_image_biosimg
addtask do_rootfs_wicenv after do_image before do_image_gptimg

_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS = " \
    ${@d.getVarFlag('do_image_wic', 'depends', False)} \
    coreutils-native:do_populate_sysroot \
    wic-tools:do_populate_sysroot \
    dosfstools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
    mtools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
    ${@' '.join([x + ':do_populate_sysroot' for x in d.getVar('WKS_FILE_DEPENDS').split()])} \
"
_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS += "${@bb.utils.contains('MENDER_DATA_PART_FSTYPE', 'btrfs','btrfs-tools-native:do_populate_sysroot','',d)}"


# This is needed because by default 'mender-grub' feature is used on ARM, but
# it still uses U-boot as an EFI provider/launcher and requires it to be
# present.
#
# This assumes that U-boot is used on ARM, this could become problematic
# if we add support for other bootloaders on ARM, e.g Barebox.
_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS_append_mender-grub_arm =     " u-boot:do_deploy"
_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS_append_mender-grub_aarch64 = " u-boot:do_deploy"

_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS_append_mender-uboot = " u-boot:do_deploy"
_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS_append_mender-grub_mender-bios = " grub:do_deploy"

do_image_sdimg[depends] += "${_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS}"
do_image_sdimg[depends] += " ${@bb.utils.contains('SOC_FAMILY', 'rpi', 'bootfiles:do_populate_sysroot', '', d)}"

do_image_uefiimg[depends] += "${_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS} \
                              gptfdisk-native:do_populate_sysroot"

do_image_biosimg[depends] += "${_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS}"

do_image_gptimg[depends] += "${_MENDER_PART_IMAGE_DEPENDS}"

IMAGE_TYPEDEP_sdimg_append   = " ${ARTIFACTIMG_FSTYPE} dataimg"
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_uefiimg_append = " ${ARTIFACTIMG_FSTYPE} dataimg"
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_biosimg_append = " ${ARTIFACTIMG_FSTYPE} dataimg"
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_gptimg_append  = " ${ARTIFACTIMG_FSTYPE} dataimg"

# This isn't actually a dependency, but a way to avoid sdimg and uefiimg
# building simultaneously, since wic will use the same file names in both, and
# in parallel builds this is a recipe for disaster.
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_uefiimg_append = "${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'sdimg', ' sdimg', '', d)}"
# And same here.
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_biosimg_append = "${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'sdimg', ' sdimg', '', d)} ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'uefiimg', ' uefiimg', '', d)}"
# And same here.
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_gptimg_append = "${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'sdimg', ' sdimg', '', d)} \
                               ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'uefiimg', ' uefiimg', '', d)} \
                               ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'biosimg', ' biosimg', '', d)}"
# Make sure the Mender part image is available in the live installer
IMAGE_TYPEDEP_hddimg_append = "${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'sdimg', ' sdimg', '', d)} \
                               ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'gptimg', ' gptimg', '', d)} \
                               ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'uefiimg', ' uefiimg', '', d)} \
                               ${@bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'biosimg', ' biosimg', '', d)}"

# Use the Mender part image as the Live image
python() {
    if bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'sdimg', True, False, d):
        type='sdimg'
    elif bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'uefiimg', True, False, d):
        type='uefiimg'
    elif bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'biosimg', True, False, d):
        type='biosimg'
    elif bb.utils.contains('IMAGE_FSTYPES', 'gptimg', True, False, d):
        type='gptimg'
    else:
        return

    d.setVar('LIVE_ROOTFS_TYPE', type)
    d.setVar('ROOTFS', "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.%s.bz2" % type)
    d.appendVar('IMAGE_FSTYPES', ' %s.bz2 ' % type)

    # Remove the boot option on the Live installer; it won't work since Mender hard codes
    # the device nodes
    d.setVar('LABELS_LIVE_remove', 'boot')
}

# So that we can use the files from excluded paths in the full images.
do_image_sdimg[respect_exclude_path] = "0"
do_image_uefiimg[respect_exclude_path] = "0"
do_image_biosimg[respect_exclude_path] = "0"
do_image_gptimg[respect_exclude_path] = "0"

################################################################################
# Flash storage
################################################################################

mender_flash_mtdpart() {
    local file="$1"
    local size="$2"
    local kbsize="$3"
    local kboffset="$4"
    local name="$5"

    if [ "$size" = "-" ]; then
        # Remaining space.
        local total_space_kb=$(expr ${MENDER_STORAGE_TOTAL_SIZE_MB} \* 1024)
        kbsize=$(expr $total_space_kb - $kboffset)
        size=$(expr $kbsize \* 1024)
    fi

    if [ "$file" != "/dev/zero" ]; then
        local file_size=$(stat -Lc '%s' "$file")
        if [ $file_size -gt $size ]; then
            bbfatal "$file is too big to fit inside '$name' mtdpart of size $size."
        fi
    fi
    # Flash zeros first to make sure that a shorter ubimg doesn't truncate the
    # write.
    dd if="/dev/zero" \
        of="${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}.mtdimg" \
        bs=1024 \
        seek=$kboffset \
        count=$kbsize \
        conv=notrunc
    dd if="$file" \
        of="${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_NAME}.mtdimg" \
        bs=1024 \
        seek=$kboffset \
        count=$kbsize \
        conv=notrunc
}

IMAGE_CMD_mtdimg() {
    set -ex

    # We don't actually use the result from this one, it's only to trigger a
    # warning or error if the variable is not correctly set.
    mender_get_mtdparts

    ${@mender_make_mtdparts_shell_array(d)}

    local remaining_encountered=0
    local i=0
    while [ $i -lt $mtd_count ]; do
        eval local name="\"\$mtd_names_$i\""
        eval local size="\"\$mtd_sizes_$i\""
        eval local kbsize="\"\$mtd_kbsizes_$i\""
        eval local kboffset="\"\$mtd_kboffsets_$i\""

        if [ "$name" = "u-boot" ]; then
            if [ -n "${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" ]; then
                mender_flash_mtdpart "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/${MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE}" $size $kbsize $kboffset $name
            else
                bbwarn "There is a 'u-boot' mtdpart, but MENDER_IMAGE_BOOTLOADER_FILE is undefined. Filling with zeros."
                mender_flash_mtdpart "/dev/zero" $size $kbsize $kboffset $name
            fi
        elif [ "$name" = "u-boot-env" ]; then
            mender_flash_mtdpart "${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/uboot.env" $size $kbsize $kboffset $name
        elif [ "$name" = "ubi" ]; then
            mender_flash_mtdpart "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.ubimg" $size $kbsize $kboffset $name
        else
            bbwarn "Don't know how to flash mtdparts '$name'. Filling with zeros."
            mender_flash_mtdpart "/dev/zero" $size $kbsize $kboffset $name
        fi

        i=$(expr $i + 1)
    done

    ln -sfn "${IMAGE_NAME}.mtdimg" "${IMGDEPLOYDIR}/${IMAGE_LINK_NAME}.mtdimg"
}

IMAGE_TYPEDEP_mtdimg_append = " ubimg"
```

Comment: Please provide the full function.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM added the function, lmk if that helps

Comment: Hi @TaylorKaplan! If I had to guess then you might be mixing releases? Can you check if all of your layers are on the same release branch, respectively on which board are you? Feel free to poke me directly on hub.mender.io (as TheYoctoJester) too, as this is also where board integrations can be celebrated! :-)

Comment: What does the result look like in temp/run.do_image_sdimg.3123112, particularly around line 125?

Comment: I figured out the problem, I moved the line for the inline python expansion to outside the shell function and made it into an export variable. That seemed to have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to patch the meta-mender/meta-mender-core/classes/mender-part-images.bbclass file.

Specifically the parts in the code where you have ${@bb.utils.contains(...)} or ${@...} expansions, I took out of the mender_part_image function and turned them into export vars such as:

```
export IS_MENDER_BOOT="${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'mender-uboot', 'true', 'false', d)}"
mender_part_image() {
    ...
    if $IS_MENDER_BOOT; then
    ...
}
```

It's hacky but it works for me. I built this in the dunfell poky repo, but this version of meta-mender was also dunfell compat.